# JavaScript - Make blog posts have their own url not just parameters

Tags: javascript, html, url, dynamic

I am currently setting up a blog with the firebase realtime database. I have successfully made a page that pulls each post from the database and shows a preview of it on screen in a list. I also have a page for each individual post but it is not a proper page. It just uses parameters for example "domain.com/post?id=blah-blah-blah".

I would like to know if there is a way to create individual pages for each post like this "domain.com/post/blah-blah-blah". Preferably I would like to do this without a framework, but if it is not possible without one, could you suggest a framework and how to make the URLs in it?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :**

I have a GoDaddy Linux hosting server which the site is currently hosted on. Could I add something to the Web.config file?

Comment: url parameters might be what you're looking for! for express backend see: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html basically the idea is your server would be serving up a different blog post per page via HTTP request and your front end would simply render that.

Comment: Would be much simpler to use an SPA framework

Comment: What is an SPA framework?

Comment: Can you give an example of one?